# Why does py.test show my xfail tests as skipped?

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins, pytest

I have some python code and a bunch of pytest tests for it.

Some of the tests I expect to fail (that is, I am testing error handling, so I pass in inputs that should cause my code to throw exceptions.)

In order to do this, I have code like this:

```
CF_TESTDATA =[('data/1_input.csv', 'data/1_input.csv', 'utf-8'),
              pytest.mark.xfail(('data/1_input_unknown_encoding.txt', '', 'utf-8')),
              ('data/1_input_macintosh.txt', 'data/1_converted_macroman.csv', 'macroman')]
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input_file, expected_output, encoding', CF_TESTDATA)

def test_convert_file(testdir, tmpdir, input_file, expected_output, encoding):
    '''
    Test the function that converts a file to UTF-8.
    '''
...
```

The idea here is that the second run of this test, with input_file = 'data/1_input_unknown_encoding.txt', I expect the code under test to fail.

This seems to work fine, and when I run from the command line, pytest tells me that the test has xfailed. I can follow the code in the debugger and see that it is throwing the expected exception. So that's all well and good.

But Jenkins is showing this test as skkipped. When I look at the output I see the message:

```
Skip Message

expected test failure
```

Why does the test show as skipped? It seems like the test runs, and fails as expected. That's not the same as the test being skipped.

Comment: When you're running from Jenkins, are you running it from the same current directory as in interactive run?

Comment: I'm guessing Jenkins reads the JUnitXML output? I'm guessing JUnitXML simply hasn't a way to say xfail, so pytest uses skip. But I don't actually know.

Comment: @TheCompiler yes jenkins junit plugin reads junit xml. junit xml contains a tag like `<skipped message="the skipped message">` for skipped or expected fail tests. That message can be a custom message from message in skip() call. In case of xfail or xpass the message is set by pytest to "expected test failure" or "xfail-marked test passes unexpectedly".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that I am using xfail incorrectly. It should not be used to expect test failure. It does not do that. If the test fails or does not fail, it is recorded as passing.

What I need to do instead is change the tests to catch the exception I expect, and error out if the exception is not thrown. Then I will remove the xfails.

xfail seems to be for cases when you have a test temporarily failing, and you want your test suite to pass. So it does not so much expect a failure, as not care about a failure.

While the test is still run, the results are not checked, and so it's reasonable for the report to show that this test was skipped.

My tests now look like this:

```
# Test the run function. 
ex1 = False 
try:
        result = main.run(base_dir + '/'+ input_file, \
                 client_config['properties']) 
except ValueError as e:
        ex1 = True
        print e

if expect_fail:
        assert ex1 
else:
        assert not ex1
        assert filecmp.cmp(result, base_dir + '/' + expected_output), \
            "Ouput file is not the same as the expected file: " + expected_output
```

Comment: See http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions

Comment: It should be used to expect failures, the problem is that your test should not fail when the code under test behaves correctly (throws an exception).  Your test should only fail when the code does *not* behave correctly (fails to throw an exception).

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to explain why expectedFail is marked as skipped.

In py.test test status can be:

- passed or
- failed or
- skipped. xfail (aka expectedFailure) is a subset of skipped:

  - A @unittest.skip("message") tagged test does not run.
  - A @unittest.expectedFailure tagged test does run and:

    - skipped message is set to xfail "expected test failure" if the result is fail or
    - xpass "xfail-marked test passes unexpectedly" if the result is pass.

Reference:

http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html